# How to combine Transpose, Concatenate & IF in excel/ google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Table 1

| Employee | Country |
| --- | --- |
| John | USA |
| Davis | Australia |
| Maria | Australia |
| Nancy | USA |

Table 2

| Country | Employee | Clients |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | ?? | Johnson |
|  |  | Twitter |
|  |  | FaceBook |
|  |  | IBM |
|  |  | RedHat |
|  |  | Phizer |

?? should correspond to data from Table 1 with the Country filter.

For our example, it would be `John, Nancy` in the same cell, preferably in the next line (alt+enter)

`John,`

`Nancy`

I have tried to concatenate + transpose, but I am unable to make it work.

Moreover, I am unable to find any way to do the equivalent of sumif() in transpose.

Comment: Please choose which app you are using. Either Excel or GS and remove the remaining tags from the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `google-sheet` you may try below formula-

```
 =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=H2))
```

`CHAR(10)` is for line break.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=BYROW(D5:D10, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), 1, IFERROR(FILTER(A:A, B:B=x)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Excel use Pivot Tables:

[image]

[Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Just take field Country and Employee into *Rows* section and Pivot Table will do the rest. Employees will not be in same cell, will be in different but it's the structure you want. And it's really really easy.